# How to make character walk on specific route in monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am new to programming, so for some of you this will be quite primitive. I am basically trying to make game in which the chracter (player) is walking towards the point where was clicked. And i wanna ask what would be the simpliest way to make it follow the road and not going through fences, buildings, etc.

[Preview (bad quality)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN5rg.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you're new, I'll give you some pointers, rather than downvote your poorly phrased question. Your question is not likely to get responses because it is very broad, which makes any answer opinion-based, and therefore not a great fit for StackOverflow. You should review the "How to ask a good question" post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also, the problem you're working on is not a beginner problem; it requires understanding of graph theory and pathfinding algorithms. Check out this website for demo: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the player character go straight from A to B with some collision on the fences so they don't walk right through. This has the downside of not always working (like when the only path involves walking around an obstacle) and of course requires collision detection to be implemented.

The other method is to implement a simple grid-based pathfinding algorithm such as A* mentioned before. A* isn't the easiest algorithm to learn though for an absolute beginner, at least in my opinion, so it helps for sure to watch a good tutorial on the subject.
Sebastian Lague made a [great video on A* pathfinding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE&ab_channel=SebastianLague) which can really make the algorithm a lot easier to digest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement path finding and considering walkable / non-walkable areas. One frequently used algorithm for path finindg is the A* (A star) algorithm.